# Selecting correct logger for global error handling in WCF application

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, nlog

I've set up global error handling following this guide https://dzone.com/articles/logging-all-unhandled

I'm using Nlog instead of Log4Net so my logger object is `private static readonly Logger logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();`. When running this for a handled exception in a class, it would write to that class's logger, allowing me to see which class generated the exception. When the exception is logged by the global exception handler it is logged by the default exception handler class. Is there any way to view the originating class from within the error handler class?

Even if it's not possible to write it to the class-specific logger object, having the class name would at least allow me to put it in the message string

Comment: If the output NLog Target Layout includes `${exception:format=tostring}` then you should have the full stacktrace from the exception. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Exception-layout-renderer

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/899342/WCF-Global-Exception-Handling) can help you.